# Django 1.7 AppConfig v. MyModelAppConfig

Tags: django, django-1.7

We're just implementing Django AppConfig on a new 1.7 project and were wondering what the correct "Python"/"Django" way to name this would be?

Is it better to explicitly name it:

```
class MyModelConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
```

Or is there any good reason why it can't be named?:

```
class AppConfig(AppConfig):
    ...
```

It's tidier but may not be right.

Is there any reason that's not obvious *not* to do it the second way?

The naming in the documentation uses the first way in examples, but is there any good reason? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/

Answer (score 2):

It is often a bad idea to hide names. If you define a new class `AppConfig` like that, you can no longer access the old `AppConfig` base class. Other approaches are e.g.:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig as BaseAppConfig

class AppConfig(BaseAppConfig):
```

Or:

```
from django import apps

class AppConfig(apps.AppConfig):
```

Now, this is considered a good design in general, and is not even necessary in this case, as you normally only use a single `AppConfig` for each app. However, it's always a good idea to make good design patterns a habit rather than an exception when it breaks. There might even be edge-cases where you need multiple app configs for different situations.